# What is the longest typical length of time for a Sonoma county superior court jury deliberations?

Tags: california, jury, verdict

Wayne Hsiung is currently awaiting a jury verdict from a trial in Sonoma County Superior Court for some misdemeanour and some felony charges. How much longer would he likely be waiting for a verdict for as he’s not yet received one now?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about the law - it's asking for a very specific niche statistic

Comment: Wouldn't we agree, though, that it's a niche statistic about the law?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to @ohwilleke in a comment on another post,

> Deliberations can take up to a week or two, although they are usually shorter. In this case, there is a good chance that the jury will push to be done before the end of the day on Friday so that they don't have to return on Monday. Deliberations are longer in longer trials because many juries want to review all the evidence that they heard once together before ruling.